# Put mysql data into html table with edit buttons

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

I'm attempting to make a ticket system for out smaller company. I've made a submission form that saves to a mySQL database. I can save the data into the table and pull the date into a html table. I've been searching all day, however, to figure out how to put in a cell that will allow me to click a button, link, or whatever to change that row to completed. I have a field in the database for it, but I don't know how to get that cell into the table or how to get the link to understand which row I'm talking about. I've been searching Google for awhile and only getting how to make a html table with mySQL data or how to INSERT into a mySQL table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need 3 things: an [`UPDATE` statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html), the field in the row you want to update, and some [unique way of identifying which row](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) (entry) you want to update.

You'll probably want to create a link something similar to:

```
<a href='/path/to/update.php?id=myUniqueIdentifier'>complete</a>
```

and on the php page you'll want to use the `$_GET['id']` passed (make sure to use [msyql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)) to `UPDATE` your row and set your completed flag to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

Lynda.com has a solid MySQL essentials video that has something very similar to what you are looking for. It would definitely be a good starting point for building your own custom solution. Or I'm sure you could just use their user interface to interact with mysql inside the browser.

I have no affiliation with Lynda.com - I just used their site to learn almost everything i know about programming.